# Reshape operator

Tags: terminology

I am reshaping matrices into a single vector. This is the [function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) that I am using. Is there a conventional symbol for this operation (latex command)?

Comment: The APL programming language called this the "ravel" operator and just used a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is typically denoted by the operator $\text{vec}(\cdot)$.
2. In MATLAB, you could also just use the built-in colon operator (e.g. b = A(:)), which will stack entries of a matrix in column-major order.